# Time difference in Excel with format

Tags: excel, time, format, formula, difference

I have cells with time value downloaded from STDF file format as below

Start time                Finish Time

01/01/2022 - 00:43       01/02/2022 - 00:57

I need to format these cells correctly and get the total time from start to finish   in this case 24 hours and 14 minutes

I used Timevalue() formula but its not working with the format i have

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72518661/4961700

Comment: Split your data in 2 columns and then use a formula to get desired output