# Allocating hours for timesheets based on shift start/end times

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Been battling for longer than I'd like to admit on this, would greatly appreciate feedback.

I need to see how many hours are worked during weekday day, weekday night, saturday, sunday, public holiday hours - based on when these shift times start.

I tried this with a very complicated nested IF function, but the rules and criteria got a bit out of hand and am really hoping for a simpler solution.

Essentially the rules are as follows (Weekdays are Monday to Friday):

Week day hours are from 07:30 until 16:00 (unless it's a public holiday).

Week night hours are from 16:00 until 07:30 the following morning (unless it's a public holiday or a Friday, Friday night hours are until midnight, then it becomes staturday hours).

Saturday hours are from midnight to midnight.

Sunday and public holiday hours are from midnight until 07:30 Monday/the following morning.

[image: I'll have multiple of these grids, different groups have different time rules]

The end result needs to look something like this (there will be a total hour check, along with some other overtime specific checks) - feel free to recommend something else:

[image]

My end goal, is to have this all in a table - where each rule grid has their own column, and I can simply update the start end times, and refresh a pivot table that has the information I need.

If there's a different Excel-related solution, i.e, PowerQuery, PowerPivot etc. I'm down to try that as well.

Comment: So many posts about t6his, see this as one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72518661/4961700

Comment: That post's solution doesn't work on my problem.

Ignores minutes, and for some reason gives me the same value doesn't matter what I change my "day start/day end" times to.

Comment: So use the minute() function and add minutes…