# Calculate hours between two times

Tags: excel

I am trying to calculate the hour between two times, for instance:

actual time: 9:42:00 AM (by using today() formula)

ending time: 05:00:00 PM

**time left: 7:18**

Having said that, I tried to use the formula today() in the actual time cell and then input manually the ending time. However it is giving me ####### as the output. I already changed for all the different date/time options and it is still appearing #####. Is there any other alternative way of calculating the time remaining?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72518661/4961700 and give it a vote if it helps.

Comment: It works if I input manually the starting hour but it doesnt work when using the now() formula

Comment: And vote for the answer that I linked to, not the comment...

Answer (score 0):

So, works with now() and formatted as time:

[image]

Not sure where you are using today() though.

Comment: I believe you are almost there, but right now D8 is telling me how much time passed from 13:00 to 17:17. I want to know how much time I have left if my deadline is 13:00. So, if you change b8 for 19:00 it has to give the time I have left